# How to Get Last Value That Equals to X in json Array

Tags: arrays, json, api

I'm needing to get the 'num' value where the last 'observed' is equal to "observed" in the following response given below (eg the one before 'estimated').

The return updates the next 'estimated' to 'observed' every three hours and I need to display the updated 'num' value each time the API is requested.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

```js
axios.get('http://url_to_api')
  .then(function (response) => {
   //do the magic here to get last observed val
    console.log(LAST_OBSERVED_VAL)
  })
```

The Response:

```js
[  
  [  
    "time_tag",
    "num",
    "observed",
    "scale"
  ],
  [  
    "2019-01-16 18:00:00",
    "2",
    "observed",
    null
  ],
  [  
    "2019-01-16 21:00:00",
    "3",
    "observed",
    null
  ],
  [  
    "2019-01-17 00:00:00",
    "3",  // <-- Get this value
    "observed",
    null
  ],
  [  
    "2019-01-17 03:00:00",
    "2",
    "estimated",
    null
  ],
  [  
    "2019-01-17 06:00:00",
    "2",
    "estimated",
    null
  ],
  [  
    "2019-01-18 00:00:00",
    "2",
    "predicted",
    null
  ],
  [  
    "2019-01-18 03:00:00",
    "1",
    "predicted",
    null
  ],
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert something like this magic:

```
var k, LAST_OBSERVED_VAL = '';
for (k = response.data.length-1; k >= 0; k--)
{
    if (response.data[k][2] == "observed")
    {
        LAST_OBSERVED_VAL = response.data[k][1];
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate you giving an answer - I just haven't gotten my head wrapped around these type of iterations. However, this gives a return of `null`. Would it be more helpful if you look over [this returned json array](https://services.swpc.noaa.gov/products/noaa-planetary-k-index-forecast.json)?

Comment: @CelticParser: can you check what is in response.data variable? (using for instance console.log(response.data))